# Run a script when the page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to execute a script tag `<script>` as soon as the website load.

I tried a lot of codes but it doesn't satisfy me.

Comment: You can use window.onload = function(){} and add your javascript inside

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it satisfy you?

Comment: You're telling that you tried a lot of codes but they didn't satisfy you. Please clarify what you tried and why they didn't satisfy you. Otherwise you may end up similar answers with you already tried.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you can add tag after loading page:

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
   var script = document.createElement('script'); 
   script.async = "true";
   script.src = "http://my-site.com/script.js";
   let scriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   script.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptElement);
  }
  
</script>
```

Or you can use `defer`. It will be run after load page:

```html
 <script src="myLoadPage.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I am not going to run a function, i want to run a script tag

Comment: I changed my answer by two answers. There isn't other way for your question.